# How to get all insights statistics on company on ads of marketing api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want get statistics on company to all ads of company?
I'm getting statistics now on company, but don't of ads, with the help faceebok php sdk.

Current codes:

```
$params =  [
        AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
        AdsInsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS,
        AdsInsightsFields::SPEND,
        AdsInsightsFields::CLICKS,
        AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
        AdsInsightsFields::REACH,
        AdsInsightsFields::GENDER_TARGETING
    ];

    $cursor = $this->Entity->getInsights($params, ['end_time' => (new \DateTime('now'))->getTimestamp()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$params =  [
        AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
        AdsInsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS,
        AdsInsightsFields::SPEND,
        AdsInsightsFields::CLICKS,
        AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
        AdsInsightsFields::REACH,
        AdsInsightsFields::GENDER_TARGETING,
        AdsInsightsFields::ADSET_ID
    ];
    //dd($params);
    $cursor = $this->Entity->getInsights($params, [
        'end_time' => (new \DateTime('now'))->getTimestamp(),
        'level'    => 'adset', // adset(groups ads) or ad(ad statistics)
        ''

    ]);
    $insights = [];
    foreach($cursor->getObjects() as $insight) {
       // dd($insight->getData());
        $insights[] = array_only($insight->getData($params), $params);
    }
```